# Eigen how to concatenate matrix along a specific dimension?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have two eigen matrices and I would like to concatenate them, like in matlab `cat(0, A, B)`

Is there anything equivalent in eigen?

Thanks.

Comment: That matlab code does not work.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use the comma initializer syntax for that.

Horizontally:

```
MatrixXd C(A.rows(), A.cols()+B.cols());
C << A, B;
```

Vertically:

```
// eigen uses provided dimensions in declaration to determine
// concatenation direction
MatrixXd D(A.rows()+B.rows(), A.cols()); // <-- D(A.rows() + B.rows(), ...)
D << A, B; // <-- syntax is the same for vertical and horizontal concatenation
```

For readability, one might format vertical concatenations with whitespace:

```
D << A,
     B; // <-- But this is for readability only.
```

Comment: How does Eigen figure out whether to concatenate the matrices vertically or horizontally? Is it based on the size of the output matrix?

Comment: yes, you guessed right. (It's not based on the code formatting!)

Comment: Not yet for sparse matrices.

Comment: @ggael I don't think this "guessing" is very intuitive. It's not very explicit and it also requires quite a lot of "trust" that it really does "the right thing". Wouldn't it be better to handle this more explicitly? (It could be like numpy's `concatenate`/`hstack`/`vstack` or with the comma-initializer, I don't mind, though the numpy-way is used in lots of matrix libraries).

Comment: @Ela782 And in the case where A.rows() == A.cols()+B.cols() (i.e. where the matrices could be stacked horizontally or vertically if allowing transposing) then the matrices will not be transposed. So stacking 3 Vector3d will stack them vertically because vectors are single-column matrices in Eigen. Stacking a square number of square matrices is done in the same order as elements are inserted in a matrix with the operator << i.e. top to bottom, left to right.

Comment: There is no implicit transposition in comma initializer and if the sizes do not match, or if there is not enough to too many elements, then it triggers an assert. `hstack/vstack` covers slightly different usages than the comma initializer and I agree this would be a welcome feature. IIRC there is some proof-of-concept code hanging somewhere....

Answer (score 8):

I'd use [Eigen's block indexing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) in a way similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404811/append-column-to-matrix-using-eigen-library) (which concatenates to an existing matrix).

The block indexing avoids the direction ambiguity in the accepted approach, and is pretty compact syntax. The following is equivalent to `C = cat(2, A, B)` in MATLAB:

```
MatrixXd C(A.rows(), A.cols()+B.cols());
C.leftCols(A.cols()) = A;
C.rightCols(B.cols()) = B;
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a slightly different use case: To vertically stack a std::vector of Eigen matrices. Here is how I implemented a function which is more general purpose. Let me know if this can be further improved:

```
// matrix_eig = Eigen::MatrixXf in RowMajor format
matrix_eig VStack(const std::vector<matrix_eig> &mat_vec) {
  assert(!mat_vec.empty());
  long num_cols = mat_vec[0].cols();
  size_t num_rows = 0;
  for (size_t mat_idx = 0; mat_idx < mat_vec.size(); ++mat_idx) {
    assert(mat_vec[mat_idx].cols() == num_cols);
    num_rows += mat_vec[mat_idx].rows();
  }
  matrix_eig vstacked_mat(num_rows, num_cols);
  size_t row_offset = 0;
  for (size_t mat_idx = 0; mat_idx < mat_vec.size(); ++mat_idx) {
    long cur_rows = mat_vec[mat_idx].rows();
    vstacked_mat.middleRows(row_offset, cur_rows) = mat_vec[mat_idx];
    row_offset +=  cur_rows;
  }
  return vstacked_mat;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this dynamic solution in the way that the number of matrices is not known in advance. 
However, beware of stl containers (i.e. vectors) and eigen https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html

Comment: good, thanks for the solution. This can be a feature request!