# how to concatenate Vectors in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have two vectorXd in my program and I like to concatenate them into one vector, so that the second one's values goes after the first one, I found this for matrix but it doesn't seem to work on Vectors:

[Eigen how to concatenate matrix along a specific dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496157/eigen-how-to-concatenate-matrix-along-a-specific-dimension)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like so, assuming you have `vec1` and `vec2` already:

```
VectorXd vec_joined(vec1.size() + vec2.size());
vec_joined << vec1, vec2;
```

(Note that the vector types are simply typedefs of matrix types constrained to have only one column.)

Further reading: [Advanced initialization](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the first line above be `VectorXd vec_joined( vec1.rows() + vec2.rows() );`? Without first initializing the vector `vec_joined` it will spit assertion failures ...

Comment: Would this syntax work with more than two vectors? For example, provided proper initialisation has been done before hand: `vec_joined << vec1, vec2, vec3;`