# What's the right type for a join_rows() function?

Tags: c++, eigen

I wrote a function that [joins the rows of two 2D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496157/eigen-how-to-concatenate-matrix-along-a-specific-dimension):

```
template <typename S, typename T>
Array<typename S::Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic> join_rows(const ArrayBase<S> & A, const ArrayBase<T> & B) {
    Array<typename S::Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic> C (A.rows(), A.cols()+B.cols());
    C << A, B;
    return C;
}
```

I would like to write a more general function that can join more than two arrays.

It should be able to work with any iterable container, eg. `std::list` or `std::vector`, so I would use a template template paratemeter.

I can easily right the function body with two for loops, that's not the issue, I'm just struggling to figure out what the right type for such a function would be.

(ps. I'm not even sure if my above code has the best type, but it seems to do the job)

Comment: You may consider taking the pair of iterators, or just an arbitrary container. There is no necessity for a template template parameter I think.

Comment: Can you even have a `vector` of 2D arrays? Different arrays (can) have different types, right?

Comment: Could you give some example code of how you would call this function?

Comment: @IlyaPopov, if I take the pair of iterators, how will I know how many columns i have?

Comment: @user357269 You'd have to loop through the entire sequence and count. I'm not sure what the type of the iterators would be, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to declare a vector of arbitrary `Array`s, but you can implement a function template that combines one or more arguments directly passed to it. This is typically done by calling itself recursively, processing each successive argument:

```
// end case (one argument): just forward the same array
template <typename T>
T&& join_rows(T&& A) {
    return std::forward<T>(A);
}

// main function template: two or more arguments
template <typename S, typename T, typename... R>
Array<typename S::Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic> join_rows(const ArrayBase<S>& A,
                                                      const ArrayBase<T>& B,
                                                      const ArrayBase<R>&... rest) {
    Array<typename S::Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic> C(A.rows(), A.cols()+B.cols());
    C << A, B;
    return join_rows(C, rest...); // call with the first two arguments combined
}
```

Example to illustrate usage:

```
int main() {
    Array<int, 1, 3> arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
    Array<int, 1, 2> arr2 = {4, 5};
    Array<int, 1, 4> arr3 = {9, 8, 7, 6};

    cout << join_rows(arr1, arr2, arr3.reverse()) << endl; // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to restrict the one-argument `join_rows` to only accept `Eigen::Array`s, add an `std::enable_if` checking for an `ArrayBase<T>` base class:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<ArrayBase<std::decay_t<T>>,std::decay_t<T>>::value, T&&>
join_rows(T&& A) {
    return std::forward<T>(A);
}
```

For large `Array`s, there might be more efficient ways to implement this. You could probably return a proxy object that will only allocate one new `Array` object.