# Storing a list of Eigen arrays

Tags: c++, c++14, eigen

I would like to store a collection of Eigen arrays in an `std::list` or `std::vector`.

My arrays have different types, some `Array<Scalar, 1, Dynamic>`, some `Array<Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic>`, so I'm not sure what template argument to give `std::list`.

Ideas:

- Cast everything to `Dynamic` and store as `std::list<Array<Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic>>`,  but this feels like needless copying
- `boost::variant`?

For those less familiar with Eigen, `Dynamic` means `-1`.

For more context, see here: [What's the right type for a join_rows() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998116/whats-the-right-type-for-a-join-rows-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayXf`, `ArrayXXd`, `Array3i`, etc. are all different types.
Therefore, your question boils down to: Is there a STL container that allows heterogeneous types? The short answer to that is: No.
The long answer to that is: No, but...

There are alternatives. As you pointed out, you could use a `list`/`vector` of [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html) (explicitly list all types) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) (effectively allow any type). You could also use a `list`/`vector<void*>` and `static_cast` at every usage (personally, not my preferred option).

Comment: There was a typo in my question, I'm actually using all the same scalar types

Comment: @user357269 Even with the same scalar types, the `Array`s are different types.