# Eigen vertical stacking rows into Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I would like to create a matrix of size `2N x 9` where `N` is a dynamic value by vertical stacking `2N` `1x9` matrices.

Here's what I tried doing.

```
using CoefficientMatrix = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 9>;
using CoefficientRow = Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, 9>;

CoefficientMatrix A(2*N, 9);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    CoefficientRow ax;
    CoefficientRow ay;
    // fill in ax and ay
    A << ax, ay;
}
```

But, I get the following runtime error.

```
Assertion failed: (((m_row+m_currentBlockRows) == m_xpr.rows() || m_xpr.cols() == 0) && m_col == m_xpr.cols() && "Too few coefficients passed to comma initializer (operator<<)"), function finished, file /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CommaInitializer.h, line 120.
```

I tried parsing through the assertion syntax but I'm not sure what those internal variable names are referring to in terms of my code (new to Eigen).

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Write something like this:

```
CoefficientMatrix A(2*N, 9);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    CoefficientRow ax;
    CoefficientRow ay;
    // fill in ax and ay
    A.row(2*i)   = ax;
    A.row(2*i+1) = ay;
}
```

---

The reason of your error is (as Avi explained) that the `operator<<` is intended to fill an entire matrix at once. In fact, calling `operator<<(Array &A, Array const &b)` assigns `b` to the top-left corner of `A` and returns a proxy-object which holds a reference to `A` and keeps track of how much entries of `A` already got assigned to (stored in `m_row`, `m_currentBlockRows`, `m_col`) and overloads `operator,` which assigns the next expression to the corresponding position of `a` and increases the position accordingly. Finally, when that proxy object gets destructed (which usually happens "at the `;`") the destructor checks if all entries of `A` have been filled (and raises a failed assertion, if not).

If you prefer to use the `<< ,` syntax you could also write:

```
    A.middleRows<2>(2*i) << ax, ay;
```

With optimizations enabled that should generate the same code as the simple implementation above (so choose whichever is easier to read for you).

---

N.B.: You could technically (ab)use the `CommaInitializer` in a loop, by constructing it outside the loop, assigning it to a variable and then only use the `,` operator inside the loop. I'll intentionally won't give more details on how to do that ...

Comment: I like the idea of using `middleRows`. Congrats on the 10K.

Answer (score 3):

The overload for `operator <<` fills the entire matrix at once. If the dimensions don't match, you get the runtime error you encountered.

Look at it this way. Assume that the code works as you wanted (`operator <<` inserted a single row? two rows at a time?). How do two consecutive calls to `operator <<` work? Does every matrix now have to track how many times `operator <<` was called? Or conversely, if a partial row was inserted, how should that be handled?

Comment: Thanks, so in which situation would you want to use this operator? Other posts on SO suggest that it’s used for stacking,

Comment: @Carpetfizz See [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html) for some simple usage examples.

Comment: Why does it work here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496281/896112

Comment: There, Gael is fully initializing the matrix in one go. In your code, you have `N` calls of `A << ax, ay;`. Gael does `C << A, B;` once where the dimensions of `A` plus `B` next to each other equal the dimensions of `C`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Avi, makes sense.