# How to declare Eigen matrix and then initialize it through nested loop

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to do whats written in the title, I have tried following code:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> Tensor;

// should return a matrix of shape (batch_size, 1840)
Eigen::MatrixXd flatten(Tensor x)
{
    int channels = x.size(); // always 10
    int batch = x[0].size(); // varies
    int columns = x[0][0].size(); // always 184

    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1840> matrix;
    for (unsigned int b = 0; b < batch; b++)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            for (unsigned int c = 0; c < channels; c++)
            {
                matrix << x[c][b][i]; // I also tried this: matrix(b, i+c) = x[c][b][i];
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

But the code either aborts with `abort() has been called` message or its giving me an `Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000`

Whats the proper way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never told the matrix what size it should be. You have to resize the matrix before writing to it.

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1840> matrix;
matrix.resize(batch, 1840);
for (unsigned int b = 0; b < batch; b++)
    ...
```

A second problem with your code is that `operator<<` does not behave like `push_back` of std containers. It initializes an entire (properly sized) matrix at once, not with NxMxL calls.

An unrelated performance issue with the code is that the `Tensor x` is passed by value, incurring a copy. Pass by (const) reference instead:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd flatten(const Tensor& x)
{ ...
```

Comment: I see, did not know matrix needed to be resized. I used `=` operator for assignment, and it works like charm. Thanks

Comment: You also might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577439/eigen-vertical-stacking-rows-into-matrix).