# `a,b,c` are both type `Eigen::ArrayXd`. What's the shape of `{a,b,c}`?

Tags: c++, eigen

from others' codes in the codebase, there is an assignment like `z = {a,b,c}` where `z` has type `Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::ArrayXd, 3, 1>`, but I have no idea how it forms this, and how to access a member of `a` such as `a[1]` for example in this Matrix.

I have to say it is much easier to understand with `numpy.vstack` in Python.

the docs of Eigen https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html says it should be a scalar type in template `Matrix<typename Scalar, int RowsAtCompileTime, int ColsAtCompileTime>`
so how is `Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::ArrayXd,3,1>` even possible since `Eigen::ArrayXd` is not a scalar type?

Comment: Can you define what is `{a, b, c}`? If you ask about how to concatenate the matrices, [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496157/eigen-how-to-concatenate-matrix-along-a-specific-dimension). Otherwise, if you want to know if it's possible to have a "matrix of eigen matrices" - yes it is, but you need to follow the guidelines for [using custom scalars](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html#user_defined_scalars) (not sure if it makes sense, though).

Comment: Where are those "other's codes" that gave you this idea?

Comment: @pptaszni I'm reading others' codes in my company's codebase, it is an assignment where it's like `arr = {a,b,c}` and `arr` is `Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::ArrayXd, 3, 1>` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of `Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::ArrayXd, 3, 1>` is 3 rows x 1 column. Each element contains an array (not a matrix or vector, from math POV) of size N (dynamic).

That's it, all the operations will be defined like usual. In particular, given:

```
Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::ArrayXd, 3, 1> m = {a, b, c};
```

the transposition of this matrix will have a shape (1,3), and the matrix multiplication result

```
auto prod = m * m.transpose();
```

will be 3x3 matrix with elements

```
aa ab ac
ba bb bc
ca cb cc
```

And since your elements are of type `Eigen::ArrayXd`, they will be multiplied element-wise.

[Small demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bj8ec9xsf)

Comment: thank you! Is the multiplication of arrays element-wise by default in C++?

Comment: Not in C++ in general, but Eigen library defines it like that. See [the documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) with some examples.

Comment: thank you, but I still dont quite get the assignment, like `{a,b,c}` is assumed to be shape {3,1}?

Comment: Yes, the shape is determined by the Matrix type you are assigning to. So in your case it's 3 rows x 1 column with element type being Array of dynamic size (elements a, b, c don't even need to have the same size). Don't think about it from the mathematical point of view (well, unless your colleagues have some special interpretation for these types), treat it like a container with fancy operations.